# qlikview MapSubString

Tags: qlikview, loaddata

I am using mapping load with MapSubString but it doesnt work for searching the sentence start and ends with text. 
For example : All below cases will be mapped with Network fault.

- Network Element fault
- Network Radio equipment fault
- Network had some unknown fault

So the search must be something like Network*fault
I cannot make it with wildmatch because i have around 280 keywords to be searched.

Thanks in advance

```
Keywords:
Mapping load Upper(Keyword) as Keyword, '$' &Todo& '~' as Todo
FROM [$(ROOTPATH)\Config\projects\$(vPROJECTNAME)\Ticket_Defect_Keyword.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet1);

load ticket_id, TextBetween(MapSubString('Keywords', Upper(Remark&'-'&Failure_Detail)), '$', '~') as Keyword_Data
FROM F_TICKET
```

Comment: Please share few example rows which should be matching from "Ticket_Defect_Keyword.xlsx" and from "F_TICKET"

Answer (score 2):

You mapping load is including '$' and '~':

```
'$' &Todo& '~'
```

but [TextBetween](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2019/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/StringFunctions/TextBetween.htm) will not include them. It will just select text between them, excluding '$' and '~'.

So for sure you need to remove '$' and '~' from mapping load:

```
Keywords:
Mapping load 
    Upper(Keyword) as Keyword, 
    Todo
FROM 
    [$(ROOTPATH)\Config\projects\$(vPROJECTNAME)\Ticket_Defect_Keyword.xlsx]
    (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet1);

load 
    ticket_id, 
    TextBetween(
        MapSubString('Keywords', Upper(Remark&'-'&Failure_Detail))
    , '$', '~') as Keyword_Data
FROM 
    F_TICKET
```

Comment: if i dont use '$' &Todo& '~' for the mapping, the result of todo is adding the rest of the string after match. Text :This is a Network failure occurred after planned work.  Result of to do is : Network failure occurred after planned work instead of Network Failure

Comment: so actually $ and ~ i am using to effect "To Do" not the search

Comment: so alternatively you need to add it before and after TextBetween